# Kotlin Throw excpetion from within launch{} and catch outside

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines

I have a simple method1() that calls another method2(). Method2() launches a coroutine with launch which might throw an exception.

```
    fun method1(){

      try{
          method2()
         } catch(Exception e){
           // handle exception, (lets call this Line e) 
         } 

    }
fun method2(){

   MainScope.launch(Dispatchers.io){
         try{
             trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException()
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i()
                throw runtimeException("Message",e)
            }
    }
}

suspend fun trySomethingWhichMightThrowException()
```

My problem is the runTimeException() thrown is not propagated outside the launch and results in the app crashing.

How can i throw the exception such that the exception be caught at line e in method1()?

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception, just simply run the code in method 2 and if an exception arises it should get caught in method 1.

Comment: it is not caught in method1() since method1() is outside the launch{}. the exception that is thrown in the launch{} is not propagated out and that is my problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Side note: using Dispatchers.IO to call your suspend function `trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException()` is either unnecessary, or you shouldn't be marking `trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException` as `suspend` since it blocks. I'll treat is a blocking, non-suspend function in the below examples.

---

If you're willing to just let `method2` swallow any exceptions without propagating them to the caller (`method1()`), then you can either change `launch` to `async`:

```
fun method2(){
   MainScope.async(Dispatchers.IO){
         try {
             trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException()
         } catch(e: Exception) {
             // Log.i()
             throw RuntimeException("Message", e)
         }
    }
}
```

or use a CoroutineExceptionHandler:

```
fun method2() {
    val errorHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        Log.e("Coroutine", e.message ?: "No throwable message")
    }
    MainScope.async(Dispatchers.IO + errorHandler){
         try{
             trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException()
         } catch(e: Exception){
             // Log.i()
             throw RuntimeException("Message", e)
         }
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to catch exceptions in `method1`, there's no way to do it without making both `method1` and `method2` into either blocking or suspend functions, because they would have to await the coroutine to get the exception that was thrown.

```
suspend fun method1() {
    try {
        method2().await()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        // handle exception, (lets call this Line e) 
    } 
}

suspend fun method2() = MainScope.async(Dispatchers.IO){
     try{
         trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException()
     } catch(e: Exception){
         // Log.i()
         throw RuntimeException("Message", e)
     }
}

// or if you don't need to specify a scope for this work:

suspend fun method1() {
    try {
        method2()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        // handle exception, (lets call this Line e) 
    } 
}

suspend fun method2(): Unit = withContext(Dispatcher.IO) {
     try{
         trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException()
     } catch(e: Exception){
         // Log.i()
         throw RuntimeException("Message", e)
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. I do need to catch the exception in method1(). i.e the runTimeExcpetion thrown from method2() or the exception from trySomeIOWhichMightThrowException() itself. 


My problem is, method1() is actually in a different class altogether and it is written in Java so i do not have coroutines or suspend functionality there and hence can not make method1() suspend. I created method2() just for this transition. 


method1() calls method2() and method2() start a coroutine to do a disk write in background.

Comment: If method1 can’t suspend, it has to block, meaning it would block its calling thread until the coroutine completes. Obviously it can’t predict if the coroutine will throw in the future so it has to wait for it. I suppose it could internally spawn a thread just to do that.